# Adding extra results to query result

Tags: mysql

I'm really in a ditch due to the previous group of coders giving me this project to do without any information. Not even an ERD to work with. This is something I've slowly dug out from exploring parts of the database. 
 
**ORDER TABLE**

```
OrderID
DateOrdered
TotalAmt
```

**ORDER PRODUCT TABLE**

```
OrderProductID
OrderID
ProductID
ProductName
```

I've got 2 tables which consists of the above variables.
The query results I've gotten is as such

```
Order Date       OrderID      ProductID   Product Name 

10/02/2015       123456       000012      Product 1
10/04/2015       123472       000002      Product 4
```

What I would like to add is the totalamt into the results. Is there any possible way to do it? Something like below or of similar concept. Based on my limited beginner knowledge, i believe is impossible to achieve as SQL does not work this way because ORDER TABLE would consists of 1 or more of ORDER PRODUCT TABLE. But hoping for some ideas on how I can do it. Is it possible?

```
Order Date       OrderID      ProductID   Product Name  Total Amount

10/02/2015       123456       000012      Product 1     
10/02/2015       123456                                 10
10/04/2015       123472       000002      Product 4
10/04/2015       123472                                 8
```

Comment: can you show the query !

Comment: Hi, Whether the 'Total Amount' field is required in the same row or in the next row?